# OO Design Decision: Class build itself from Database or have builder class / factory

Tags: oop, design-patterns, database-design, object-oriented-analysis

I'm building a new application and can't decide which way to go on this question.

Should the database data oriented classes build themselves from the database with methods like:

```
class Foo 
{
    public buildYourselfFromDatabaseForID(...)
    //and overloading the constructor etc.
    public commitYourselfToTheDatabase();
}
```

or should I build a database management class / factory that will handle all the SQL and build the objects for me, such as:

```
Foo var = dbManager->createMeAFooFromID(id);
// Make some changes to var

dbManger->commitChangesToFoo(var);
```

I've worked on projects doing it both ways before, but can't really decide which way to go on this new project and wondered what the general consensus is today?

I mean their are advantages and disadvantages to both ways, but what is the more commonly adopted approach on this? Are their any established patterns that you could point me towards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having an entity directly contact the database is a violation of [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) - it means that the class is doing, in addition to its own job, some database work, which is not its concern.

Have a factory/builder instead.

A common way to hidrate entities from the database these day is through an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) - such a library mediates between the database and your object model and deals with all database interactions on your behalf. Examples of ORMs are [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/ef.aspx), [nHibernate](http://nhforge.org/), [Dapper](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) and [more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3a.NET_object-relational_mapping_tools).

Comment: Thank you Oded, that is exactly what I was looking for. This project will be in PHP so after having had a quick look around it looks like I need to have a play with Doctrine and the Zend Framework. Thanks again for your swift and helpful response.